# Axis2 Endpoint overridden to localhost

Tags: tomcat, soap, localhost, apache-axis, endpoint

i have a problem that has been troubling me for weeks.
I have a java web application running on a Tomcat server. I use Apache as http frontend and requests are routed to tomcat via ajp. Windows Server 2008 is the operating system.

My application is tightly connected with a Sharepoint installation, and the communication is done via SOAP. I generated the proper stubs with the AXIS2 library.

On any other installation this communication works perfectly. On our new server, though, any call i make via webservices results with an error:

**Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://sharepoint.example.com/_layouts/services.asmx]
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 404 Error: not found**

I am sure that the endpoint (http://sharepoint.example.com/_layouts/services.asmx) is correct, because i can get the WSDL definition logging via remote desktop on the machine and connecting to http://sharepoint.example.com/_layouts/services.asmx?WSDL with Internet Explorer. I also am sure i can correctly invocate the services, because i tried with SOAPUI.

After a long analysis I found out that ALL of my AXIS requests, which use the correct endpoint, are actually routed to the loopback 127.0.0.1 address. I did some packet sniffing and i found out this. I also got confirmation checking the Apache logs, where i can find that /_layouts/services.asmx generate a not found error.

I don't know how, but somehow when i invoke the soap call, the connection is not open with the right server (sharepoint.example.com) but with 127.0.0.1, despite the fact that the endpoint is correctly set.

If you have ANY idea how to solve this problem, please let me know!

Comment: Check the DNS resolution of sharepoint.example.com on the machine running Tomcat?

Comment: DNS is ok, i put an entry in the hosts file and the same behavior happens if i explicitly use the IP address as endpoint (http://10.50.1.34/_layouts/services.asmx)